# C# непонятный "?" после перевода пути до файла в байты и обратно

Tags: c#, .net

В общем тут все просто:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Откуда они и почему появляются?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace testSymbol
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string s = "‪D:\\VKR\\SiteParser\\SiteParser\\bin\\Debug\\‪tes.jpeg";
            var t = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Качаю файл так

```
wc.DownloadFile ( new Uri("https://mysite.ru" + imagePath),"tes.jpeg" );
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: проблема в строке

Comment: Я уже как только не пробовал, и с @ и с правым слешем

Comment: Выведи `s.Length`. В ней два лишних символа, именно они и переходят в `?`. Откуда ты берешь эту строку? Попробуй не скопировать откуда-то и вставить, а набрать вручную - и ошибки не будет.

Comment: Дело в том, что я качаю файл (код дал), но потом когда я этот файл заливаю в xamarin , он его не видит, потому что там скрытый ? , а если я ручками переименую на тоже имя, то все хорошо

Comment: Строка приведенная в вопросе **уже неправильная**. `string s = "‪D:\\VKR\\SiteParser\\SiteParser\\bin\\Debug\\‪tes.jpeg";` вот тут в строке уже есть скрытые символы. Просто они пробельные и не отображаются, но они есть.

Comment: Это я уже понял

Comment: Отсюда вопрос: откуда именно ты взял конкретно эту строку?

Comment: Из свойств файла, кинул скрин

Comment: Вот при копировании ты и добавил свои символы.